# Integer Expression Expected - Bash Script to Conduct Linear Interpolation

Tags: bash, floating-point, interpolation

I am new to stackoverflow and writing bash scripts. I am doing a project for work and need to write a fairly simple script. I have several columns of data, one of which is time and the other is hrr, which is a continuously increasing variable with respect to time. I am trying to do a linear interpolation to find the corresponding time where hrr = 50% of the last entry in hrr.

So here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

entry=$(awk 'NR>4{print $11}' thermo.out | awk -F, '{$1=$1*a;print}' a=0.50 | tail -1 )
awk 'NR>4{print $11}' thermo.out | awk -F, '{$1=$1*b;print}' b=1.0 > hrr.out
awk 'NR>4{print $1}' thermo.out > t.out

hrr=($(<hrr.out))
t=($(<t.out))

length=${#t[@]}
end_array=$(($length-1))

#Start looping through hrr from 0 to entry that exceeds 0.50*hrr(end)
ind=0
while [ ${hrr[$ind]} -lt ${entry} ]
do
    echo "ind = $ind"
    ind=$[$ind+1]
done

exit 0
```

Clearly, I haven't written the code in the loop to find the hrr entries of interest or to interpolate. I was trying to verify that my code could succesfully enter and exit the while loop. So when I try to run what I have, I get the following error

```
./interp: line 16: [: 796.28: integer expression expected
```

So I understand that entry and elements of hrr are not integers. Is there a simple variable declaration I need to do to fix this error or can you think of a work around? I understand that doing floating point arithmetic and logic in bash script can be a hassle but I was hoping that one of you could help me. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetics at all. You can use tools like bc that supports fixed point arithmetics:

```
while (( $(bc <<< "${hrr[$ind]} < ${entry}") ))
do
    echo "ind = $ind"
    ind=$[$ind+1]
done
```

If your awk outputs in scientific notation, you could try

```
entry=$(awk 'NR>4{print $11}' thermo.out | awk -F, '{$1=$1*a; printf("%f\n",$0);}' a=0.50 | tail -1 )
awk 'NR>4{print $11}' thermo.out | awk -F, '{$1=$1*b; printf("%f\n",$0);}' b=1.0 > hrr.out
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have heard of bc, but I wanted to know if there was a way to incorporate bc into my current code or if you could propose a work around?

Comment: So now I am getting an error that states "(standard_in) 1: parse error". After perusing the forums, this seems to stem from the bc command and that I need to somehow suppress the writing of elements in scientific notation from the awk command. Thoughts about how to fix this in the awk commands or do you have a different idea of where the fix needs to occur in the code?